# Migrating .NET 5 Razor Pages Application to .NET 6: Routing and Mapping Issues

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, razor-pages

I'm in the process of migrating my ASP.NET Core Razor Pages application from .NET 5 to .NET 6, and I'm encountering an issue where the Razor Pages routing and mapping are not working as expected in .NET 6. The application was working fine in .NET 5, and I'm looking for help in identifying and resolving the problem.

Here are the relevant code snippets from my application:

```
public async Task StartAsync(Action<IServiceCollection> configureServices)
{
    this.baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

    this.host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder =>
        {
            webHostBuilder.UseStaticWebAssets();

            webHostBuilder.ConfigureServices((context, serviceCollection) =>
            {
                // Application name must be entry-point in order for Mvc to pre-populate ApplicationParts correctly
                context.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.GetName().Name;

                serviceCollection
                    .AddRazorPages()
                    .AddRazorPagesOptions(o => o.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute()))
                    .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(manager =>
                    {
                        // Set breakpoint here to troubleshoot why application parts are not loading
                    });

                configureServices.Invoke(serviceCollection);
            });

            webHostBuilder.Configure(app =>
            {
                app.UseStaticFiles();

                app.UseRouting();

                app.Use(next => async context =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await next(context);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        context.Features.Set(ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex));
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                    }
                });

                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                });
            });

            webHostBuilder.UseServer(this);
            webHostBuilder.UseContentRoot(this.baseDirectory);
        })
        .Build();

    await this.host.StartAsync();
}
```

MapRazorPages is not giving any error, but during debugging I can see that it is not mapping any pages.
[image: debug output in dotnet 6]

I have tried rewriting in new hosting model introduced by dotnet 6, but it is giving me the same problem.

Please provide guidance, suggestions, or solutions for resolving the issue with Razor Pages routing and mapping in .NET 6. Any insights or tips on changes in .NET 6 that may have affected this behavior would be greatly appreciated.